# How to Deploying ThemeForest Templates to Sharepoint 2013 Website

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there somebody out there, who is able to tell me step by step how to deploy a themeforest site template to a sharepoint website which has masterpages and subpages step-by-step?

I tried it in local environment and changes default.aspx using sharepoint designer also via browser using admin panel. nothing worked. I get a bunch of errors using sharepoint designer after changing default.aspx also I have no clue how to set the sitetemplates / mastertemplates individual.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is to big .

Ms sharepoint is not a programm where you can work with high end html5 code .
offcause you can write code . but themeforest templates are big and need a lot of knowlage to adjust it . And usage in other microsoft products dont work well with modern html5 and css3 code.